# Replacing wall plate with load bearing studs

Tags: repair, wood

[image: Note the wall plate the runs the length of the wall underneath the window]

I need to replace the wall plate under a window that itself supports half a dozen or so load bearing studs.

I have a pair of post jacks that I plan on placing atop the horizontal stud immediately in front of it.  I plan on jacking two joists that connect to the wall in question.  I then plan on cutting the target stud out with an angle grinder (set with a wood blade) and replacing it.

Good idea?  Bad?

Comment: That's a sill, not a stud. There's no such thing as a horizontal stud.

Comment: A Sawsall would be a better tool to cut the old wood out than an angle grinder. Your plan on supporting the structure is what I have done many times in the past. are talking about the king and cripple on the left

Comment: And it doesn't bear any load.

Comment: Or maybe you meant the bottom wall plate? Maybe do some study of basic framing terminology so we can have a proper conversation. :)

Comment: Bottom wall plate.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would show in a picture the structural element you want to replace.

Comment: @isherwood I disagree. It is structural and they should be careful replacing it.

Comment: As you can see I had some confusion about what board we're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I would pull the window, support the top plate with temp supports floor to plate (cut ½" long and tap the bottoms in until you see a slight  lift in the top plate) cut between the  siding and bad studs with a 12 " metal sawsall blade, remove all wood with any rot or deep fungus and reframe the whole thing. send the  studs through a table saw to make them match the adjoining studs to avoid broken drywall when reinstalling